# Orthogonal Part Operator

Tags: vector-analysis

I have some problems in acting with this operator algebrically. If I define: $$\boldsymbol p(\boldsymbol x)\in \mathbb R^3 \ \ ,\ \ P_{\alpha\beta}:=\delta_{\alpha\beta}-p_\alpha p_\beta$$
how does it affect for instance this kind of terms?

$$\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol{p}\ \\ \nabla^2\boldsymbol{p}\\   \boldsymbol{p}(\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{p})$$

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify the domains and how should we consider this $\boldsymbol{p}$? Is it a variable? Is it the *argument* of $P$? I assume $\boldsymbol{p}\in\Bbb R^n$ is a culomn vector. How do you exactly mean the $P$ operator? Is its matrix $I-\boldsymbol{p}^T\cdot\boldsymbol{p}$, or does $P$ act on the tensor space?

Comment: Yes, I need to be clearer. $\boldsymbol{p}$ is a column vector of $\mathbb R^3$, function of $\boldsymbol{x}$, respect to which the differentiation in $\nabla$ is carried. 
The $P$ operator is exactly the matrix $P_{\alpha\beta}=\delta_{\alpha\beta}-p_\alpha p_\beta$

Comment: Yes, now it's much clearer.. and how do you mean 'How does it affect' the listed terms? Do you mean $P{\boldsymbol p}\cdot \nabla(P{\boldsymbol p})$?

Comment: No, I simply meant the application of $P$ to those terms: $P(\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol{p})$

Comment: But isn't the latter one a *scalar*? How do you 'plug it' into a matrix?

Comment: $(\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol{p})_\alpha=p_\beta\partial_\beta p_\alpha$

Comment: Ah, I see.. ${\boldsymbol p}({\boldsymbol x})$ is a function of ${\boldsymbol x}$ which is a *vector*.. Yes, but then how is $\nabla$ meant? Isn't it the case that you are working on $\Bbb R^{2n}$ where ${\boldsymbol p}$ takes place on coordinates $(n+1),..,2n$?